# How to select sql complex Query where Condition And or

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table is

```
   ID       ATTRID    VALSTR   
1771373       1         1234  
1771373       3         510 
1771373       7         2016
1771373       8         05
1777623       3         5003 
1777623       7         2016 
1777623       8         05
1778103       3         520
1778103       7         2016
1778103       8         06
```

I want to select condition

```
                       AttrId = 3 AND ValStr = 510 
                       AttrId = 7 AND ValStr = 2016
                       AttrId = 8 AND ValStr = 05
```

I write this but, not run correct

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ((AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') OR
       (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  OR
       (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05')
      ) AND
      DefID = 1375552
```

How to write this query ?Can you help me please?

Comment: Your query looks correct to me.

Comment: Please give a better explanation of your desired results

Comment: you have 3 rows with `AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016'` . Why you only wanted the `ID = 1771373` ?

Comment: Query is working fine,please correct ID Value in query as ID=1771373

Comment: I want see AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510'  AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016' AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05' same time 3 condition is true so want to  see only  ID 1771373

Answer (score 3):

> I want see AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510' AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016'
>   AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05' same time 3 condition is true so want to
>   see only ID 1771373

i think this is what you are after. Is it ?

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    select  *, cnt = count(*) over (partition by ID)
    from    [Table]
    WHERE   (AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') 
    OR      (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  
    OR      (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05')
) AS D
WHERE   cnt = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

another way

```
    select a.* from yourTable a  join
    (values (3,'510'),(7,'2016'),(8,'05')) x(a,b) 
on a.attrid=x.a and a.valstr=x.b 
where  ID = 1771373
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting bit of syntax I've somehow never seen before, but as a small suggestion: I'd recommend `a.*` instead of `*` for the select list.

Comment: @Jos Farrell done it, thank you

Comment: I guess I couldn't make myself clear. I want to display results that all three conditions are provided.
For my example ;I should be display 1771373 id but without conditioning  any  id

Comment: try  select a.* from yourTable a join (values (3,'510',17713),(7,'2016',17713),(8,'05',17713)) x(a,b,c) on a.attrid=x.a and a.valstr=x.b and a.id=x.c

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ((AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') OR
       (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  OR
       (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05')
      ) AND
      ID = 1771373
```

Your query is OK.

Answer (score 1):

If the table only has ID, ATTRID and VALSTR as columns, the condition `DefID=1375552` should throw an error. It looks like you could have a typo on the ID condition too:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ((AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') OR
      (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  OR
      (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05'))
      AND ID = 1771373
```

should work fine.