# How to write a select query that provides all three conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
   ID       ATTRID    VALSTR   
1771373       1         1234  
1771373       3         510 
1771373       7         2016
1771373       8         05
1777623       3         5003 
1777623       7         2016 
1777623       8         05
1778103       3         520
1778103       7         2016
1778103       8         06
```

I want to select only three condition

```
AttrId = 3 AND ValStr = 510 
AttrId = 7 AND ValStr = 2016
AttrId = 8 AND ValStr = 05
```

My query like this, but query return all ids

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ((AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') OR
       (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  OR
       (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05')
      ) AND
      DefID = 1375552
```

I want to display results that all three conditions are provided. For my example ;I should be display 1771373 id but without conditioning any id.Can you help me please?

Comment: Where is `DefId` in your sample data?

Comment: Can you provide expected output based on your sample data

Comment: I forgot to type its same for all the rows

Comment: Can you post the result of your query?

Comment: haven't you ask this question before ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526614/how-to-select-sql-complex-query-where-condition-and-or/38527675#38527675

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HAVING clause.

This query will use a derived table containing only `ID` that answer **all** three conditions :

```
SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.Id FROM YourTable s
           WHERE (s.AttrID = 3 AND s.ValStr ='510') OR
                 (s.AttrID = 7 AND s.ValStr ='2016')  OR
                 (s.AttrID = 8 AND s.ValStr ='05')
           GROUP BY s.Id
           HAVING COUNT(distinct s.AttrID) = 3) t2
 ON(t.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: I doesnt work anyway your query

Comment: Yes It is worked many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select id from YourTable
where ((AttrID = 3 AND ValStr ='510') OR
       (AttrID = 7 AND ValStr ='2016')  OR
       (AttrID = 8 AND ValStr ='05')
      ) 
group by id having count(*)=3
```